# "Jantar de Primavera" ou "Jantar da Primavera"

Tags: português-brasileiro, tempo-verbal, locuções-adverbias

Tenho que fazer um banner e estou na dúvida de que forma escrever:

"Jantar de Primavera" ou "Jantar da Primavera"

Português do Brasil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As duas formas são gramaticais e parecem transmitir exatamente a mesma coisa.  Se eu tivesse de optar por um, talvez escolhesse **"Jantar de Primavera"** que soa mais idiomático aos meus ouvidos.

Uma **possível** diferença seria dada pela escolha do artigo, definido ou indefinido: eu diria que "um jantar de primavera", considera a possibilidade da ocorrência de outros jantares semelhantes, de primavera.  **"o Jantar da Primavera"**, no entanto, soa como se fosse o único jantar da primavera. Os outros seriam "do Inverno", "do Verão", etc.

Comment: @Centauros, mas ao utilizarmos a preposição "de" não daria o sentido que o jantar é feito de primavera? `da = de (preposição) + a (artigo)`, temos então uma contração com pronome demostrativo?

Comment: @David   É verdade que "jantar de primavera"  poderia, teoricamente, significar "um jantar feito de primavera".   Contudo ninguém imaginaria isso ao ouvir "jantar de primavera".  Quanto ao pronome demonstrativo, onde está ele?  Não o vejo.

Comment: Me referi ao pronome demonstrativo a relação entre Jantar e Primavera, não sei ao certo se é realmente pronome demonstrativo, mas me pareceu ser, desculpa :S

Comment: @David  Os pronomes demonstrativos são: este, esta, isto, aquele, aquela, aquilo, esse, essa, isso.  :)

Comment: O jantar da prima Vera ... O luau é de verão, o jantar é de primavera.